# Update Widget on System Broadcast Intent

Tags: android, android-widget, android-intent

I'm working on an Android widget that will show the current network state (i.e 1xRTT, EvDo Rev. A, WiMax, etc.). It may seem like a pointless idea, but for whatever the reason, the Evo doesn't differentiate between 1x & EvDo, it just says 3G for both, which is annoying if you're in a fringe 3G area.

Anyways, to the point: I have the widget complete and it updates with the current network just fine, but how can I make it update whenever the connection changes? I know I can use a BroadcastReceiver to catch the ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION intent the system sends on a connection change. How can I update the widget from there?

Or can I use the AppWidgetProvider to catch the intent and then update?

I know how to catch the intent, I just don't know how to update the widget once I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or can I use the AppWidgetProvider to
>   catch the intent and then update?

That should work. You will need to override `onReceive()`, look for `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` `Intents`, handle those yourself, and chain to the superclass for the default behavior.